# Does the below reasoning work to show in some special cases limit doesnt exist?

Tags: limits

Whenever we deal with limit problems specifically the case when the limit where doesnt not exist ones .

> Can we simply give the reasoning for not existing based on the fact that if its of form $\frac{L}{0}$ its always tends to $\pm \infty$ (cannot determine but we know surely its pretty large) and hence doesnt exist where L is a finite value ,likewise the case when its of form $\frac{\infty}{L}$ we will give reasoning that its approaching a value which we know is large but cannot determine ? And similarily we can say for $\infty \pm L$ forms ?

- And so only the indeterminate forms are we suposed to care  for checking limit exist or not.     We reject the determinate ones where we know a fixed value will occur always (finite ones ) and the cases discussed above  (infinite ones) ? (This question i asked so as to avoid using epsilon delta defintion of limits )

Comment: I am not an expert in this area.  Your analysis makes sense to me.

Comment: Thanks was just making sure if this is how we can avoid using epsilon delta in these special cases @user2661923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking if there are theorems of the following shape (where $L$ denotes a generic real number and all limits are happening at the same location):

- If $\lim f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim g(x) = L$, then $\lim \bigl( f(x) + g(x) \bigr) = \infty$ and $\lim \bigl( f(x) - g(x) \bigr) = \infty$ (and similarly for $-\infty$);
- If $\lim f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim g(x) = L$ with $L>0$, then $\lim \bigl( f(x)/g(x) \bigr) = \infty$ (and similarly for $-\infty$ and for $L<0$);
- If $\lim f(x) = L$ with $L\ne0$ and $\lim g(x) = 0$ (and $g(x)\ne0$ in some neighborhood of the place we're taking the limit at), then $\lim \bigl| f(x)/g(x) \bigr| = \infty$.

These are all true theorems; each one requires its own proof from the definitions of the notations $\lim f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim g(x) = L$.

Comment: Yeah i mean i was arguing just  from the simple reason i gave above, so that i can avoid epsilon delta use in all my  special cases discussed above

Comment: To be honest, I don't find your reasoning clear or sufficient; you've made some true statements, but they all have to be proved at some point (by someone, not necessarily by you).

Comment: I see understood thanks Sir